# MVVM: Передача данных между View

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Подскажите как реализовать передачу данных между **Views**.

Нужно передавать из **ViewA** цвет кнопки(Background) в **ViewB**.

В **ViewB** путём выбора происходит изменение текущего цвета и возвращается в **ViewA** в Background кнопки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если это стиль приложения, то подобное должно быть реализовано ресурсами (`DynamicResource`). Если это данные для дальнейшей обработки/хранения, и т.д., то делайте общий класс, выносите туда свойство цвета, делайте событие его обновления, и привязывайте все это.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, можете подробно объяснить как реализовать этот общий класс?

Comment: Простой класс, в нем условно `public string Color {get; private set;}`, дальше у вас выбор, либо реализовать INPC, либо свое событие. Я считаю INPC тут лишний, поэтому `public event Action<string> OnColorChanged;`, ну и метод `public void SetColor(string color) { Color = color; OnColorChanged?.Invoke(); }`. Вот вам класс, условная модель данных, внедряйте ее в нужные VM слои, подписывайтесь на событие, меняйте VM свойство по этому событию, ну и также в обратную сторону - VM свойство изменилось, вызвали метод, все. Только помните, один экземпляр должен быть класса в VM слоях.

Comment: Если к обеим View привязать один и тот же ViewModel со свойством `Color`, то всё что надо сделать - это создать привязку для фона кнопки к этому свойству (опосредованно, через SolidColorBrush), а всё остальное само будет работать